# value true if unequal to the three previous values

Tags: python, pandas

from this reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
data={'col1':[False, False, False, False,False, False, True, True]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col1'])
print (df)
df['match'] = df.col1.eq(df.col1.shift(3))
print (df)
```

the above code gives:

```
    col1
0  False
1  False
2  False
3  False
4  False
5  False
6   True
7   True

    col1  match
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False   True
4  False   True
5  False   True
6   True  False
7   True  False
```

I wonder if there is a way (similar to the above code and thus without using a 'For loop') to get true if a given value is unequal to the three previous values.

```
    col1  match
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False  False
4  False  False
5  False  False
6   True  True
7   True  False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
N = 3
df['match3'] = (df['col1']
                .rolling(N+1, min_periods=1)
                .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1].ne(x.iloc[-1]).all())
                .astype(bool)
               )
```

output:

```
    col1  match  match3
0  False  False    True
1  False  False   False
2  False  False   False
3  False   True   False
4  False   True   False
5  False   True   False
6   True  False    True
7   True  False   False
```

Or, to force the first `N` rows to be `False`:

```
N = 3
df['match3'] = (df['col1']
                .rolling(N+1)
                .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1].ne(x.iloc[-1]).all())
                .fillna(0).astype(bool)
               )
```

output:

```
    col1  match  match3
0  False  False   False
1  False  False   False
2  False  False   False
3  False   True   False
4  False   True   False
5  False   True   False
6   True  False    True
7   True  False   False
```

Comment: Many thanks, I will try that. (I also try to improve the format of my question)